# setDestenation() value in Zend_File_Transfer_Adapter_Http

Tags: php, zend-framework

`setDestination`(path) method of `Zend_File_Transfer_Adapter_Http` has a parameter which i must  set it to a directory but i don't know where is it?

how to set a path to setDestination that is valid or if it is not exist , how to create it?

Answer (score 0):

```
if(!file_exists($path))
    mkdir($path);

setDestination($path)
```

If I understood you correctly, what you want is a php code that checks whether the path you are trying to set to setDestination exists and if not create it.

EDIT:
I actually use this function alot, thats how I use it:

```
$upload = new Zend_File_Transfer_Adapter_Http();
$upload->setDestination(MyFunctionToDetermineURL());
// Gives me 'C:/wamp/www/SetOfProjects/SubFolder/Project/public/tmp'
$upload->receive();
$info = $upload->getFileInfo();
try { 
    if($info["photo"]['tmp_name'] != '') {
        MyFunction(); // Doen't matter for you
    }
} 
catch (Zend_File_Transfer_Exception $e) { 
    $this->_helper->redirector('image-upload', 'error', 'admin', array());
}
```

Comment: not only php function,setDestination() is method of Zend_File_Transfer_Adapter_Http and i want pass a path to this method. each value that i pass to this method ,is not exist.

Comment: What is `MyFunctionToDetermineURL()` ?Main criteria is this function.

Comment: It is a function I've created that asks for a controller + action + array + model + host type:
URLgenerator::getURL(null, null, array(), null, 'storage') . 'tmp'
Is what I put in the setDestination, this returns me my public folder + /tmp for the temporaries.(As you can see, it gives me:
'C:/wamp/www/SetOfProjects/SubFolder/Project/public/tmp'

Comment: so i need source of  MyFunctionToDetermineURL() !

Comment: Lol, can't help you with that, thats out companies original code.
for this example just put 'C:/YOURPATHTOPUBLIC/public/tmp

Answer (score 0):

```
$image->setLabel('Photo:')->setDestination(APPLICATION_PATH ."/../public/tmp/upload");
```